# Sine Function Accuracy on JavaScript for Angles PI rad and its Integer Multiples

Tags: javascript, math, web-applications, mathml

Sine function on JavaScript, Math.sin(), works accurately on most angles I've tried so far except for PI rad (180 degrees) and its integer multiples like 2PI, 3PI, 4PI... (in radians).
These angles were all suppost to return 0. But, for example, sine of PI rad returns 1.2246063538223773e-16.
Help! Someone please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Welcome to world of floating point computation. `1.2246063538223773e-16` is really really really close to `0`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice how small the number was. I worked it out by rounding its decimals to 16 digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

This is called **scientific notation**.

The `e-16` means that there are 16 `0`s before the number starts.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice how small the number was. I worked it out by rounding its decimals to 16 digits after the decimal point.